# CMake and Visual Studio with not default installation folder

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I am trying to build something using CMake and VS 2012. The problem is I have my VS installation on D:\Pliki programów (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0. I have no free space on my C drive.
CMake have problem with finding my VS. I tried to specify VS compiler cl.exe but it was asking for dll in the same folder anyway. I also tried to use specified toolchaing with vcvarsall.bat. But I am not sure if I am doing those things right.
I guess that I need to add VS location to CMake, but how? I tried setting PATH but it did not work.
And searching about that problem is difficult, all search engines think that I want to change installation path for my program that I want to build.

**UPDATE**

I've added `variable_watch(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM)`.

> CMake Debug Log at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
>     Variable "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM" was accessed using UNKNOWN_READ_ACCESS with
>     value .
>   CMake Debug Log at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
>     Variable "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM" was accessed using MODIFIED_ACCESS with value
>     C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe.
>   The C compiler identification is unknown
>   The CXX compiler identification is unknown
>   CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:3 (project):
>     No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.

In output file:

`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSVCRTD.lib'`

**Is CMake looking for libs in VS 11 installation folder? The thing is that VS installer put libs in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib\amd64.**

Comment: A quick test has shown that CMake actually finds VS on my PC via the `MSBuild.exe`. If I add `variable_watch(CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM)` before my `project()` command, then call something like `cmake.exe -G "Visual Studio 11" ..` I get - among other accesses to the variable - `Variable "CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM" was accessed using MODIFIED_ACCESS with value"C:/windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/MSBuild.exe".`

Comment: I've also installed VS2012 in a different directory and it worked for me. CMake does search the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0\MSBuildToolsPath`. Can you check where it's pointing to on your PC?

Answer (score 3):

For cases like this (and similar), I keep a `VCEnvCmd.bat` in my source trees:

```
call "%VS110COMNTOOLS%\..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat" amd64 & %*
```

Executing that .bat without parameters will find and run `vcvarsall.bat`, setting up the environment for the `amd64` target in the current shell (which you could change or parameterize according to your needs, like the version number embedded in that environment variable).

The nice trick is, for those Nightly / Continuous builds, you can use the .bat as a "prefix" for setting up the environment, e.g. in the task manager:

```
VCEnvCmd.bat ctest -S CTestScript.cmake,Nightly
```

The advantage is that you use what MSVC already gives you (the `VS...COMNTOOLS` variable), without having to clutter your environment further with persistent changes to `PATH` etc.

Comment: I've changed `%VS110COMNTOOLS%` it was pointing at non existing C drive location. I've updated my orginal post.

Comment: @Pepek91: If running `vcvarsall.bat` does not set up your environment correctly for a compilation, your installation is broken -- either by you fiddling with settings, or by the MSVC installer not handling non-standard paths gracefully. As I am not touching *my* (working) installation to try this out, I'm afraid I cannot help you further. ;-)